# Which layer should Value-Object be used?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, cqrs, clean-architecture, value-objects

In the following example shows a query to get an employ details. It has a `int` parameter `Id`. And there is a DTO class `EmployeeDto` which also has a field `Id` with type of `string`.

https://github.com/JasonGT/NorthwindTraders/blob/master/Src/Application/Employees/Queries/GetEmployeeDetail/GetEmployeeDetailQuery.cs

I will need to create a value-object class `EmployeeId` which contains some business logic for the employee Id. The `Id` of the entity class `Employee` will be changed to type of `EmployeeId` instead of `string`.

1. Should the type of `Id` of the DTO/Vm class `EmployeeDto` be `string`? And Automapper is used to map the `string` to `EmployeeId`? So it will be easier for UI to renter the list.
2. Should the type of the property `Id` of the query `GetEmployeeDetailQuery` be primary type string/int? Where to check if the parameter is a valid employee ID (the value object `EmployeeId` has the validation logic)?

code:

```
public class GetEmployeeDetailQuery : IRequest<EmployeeDetailVm>
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // Stay as primary type string/int?
    // public EmployeeId Id { get; set; } // or EmployeeId?

    public class GetEmployeeDetailQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetEmployeeDetailQuery, EmployeeDetailVm>
    {
        private readonly INorthwindDbContext _context;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public GetEmployeeDetailQueryHandler(INorthwindDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public async Task<EmployeeDetailVm> Handle(GetEmployeeDetailQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
           var vm = await _context.Employees
                .Where(e => e.EmployeeId == request.Id)
                .ProjectTo<EmployeeDetailVm>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider) // to be mapped to entity here
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

            return vm;
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/JasonGT/NorthwindTraders/blob/master/Src/Application/Employees/Queries/GetEmployeeDetail/GetEmployeeDetailQuery.cs

```
namespace Northwind.Application.Employees.Queries.GetEmployeeDetail
{
    public class EmployeeDetailVm : IMapFrom<Employee>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } // int/string
        // public EmployeeId Id { get; set; } // or EmployeeId?

        public string Title { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

A value object is a domain concept and, as such, should be used where other domain concepts are used.

If data goes *over-the-wire* I tend to use primitives or, if necessary, other data transfer objects.  These DTOs never have any behaviour and when I *do* want to add some method I tend to use an extension method.

Value objects, as is the case with aggregates/entities, would in all probability be encapsulated to such a degree that they would probably not be suitable for serialization.